# how to preview dynamic input fields with user data before submit using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, preview

I just started learning and implementing javascript. here is my code pls help me "how to preview dynamic input fields with user data before submit using javascript" here is sample code..

```js
var counterText = 0;
var counterpasswordfield = 0;
var counterRadioButton = 0;
var counterCheckBox = 0;
var counterTextArea = 0;
var counterButon = 0;
var counterdropdown = 0;
var counterlabel = 0;

function addAllInputs(divName, inputType) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  switch (inputType) {
    case 'text':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      if (x != null) {
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<label for='uname'>" + x + "</label>: <input type='" + inputType + "' id='myval' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
        counterText++;
      }
      break;
    case 'password':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='password' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
      counterpasswordfield++;
      break;
    case 'label':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + "<br>";
      counterlabel++;
      break;
    case 'email':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='email' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
      counterlabel++;
      break;
    case 'radio':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='radio' name='myRadioButtons[]'><br>";
      counterRadioButton++;
      break;
    case 'checkbox':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='checkbox' name='myCheckBoxes[]'><br>";
      counterCheckBox++;
      break;
    case 'dropdown':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <Select selected><option>--- Select ---</option><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select><br>";
      counterdropdown++;
      break;
    case 'textarea':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <textarea name='myTextAreas[]'>type here...</textarea>";
      counterTextArea++;
      break;
    case 'button':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<button>" + x + "</button>";
      counterButon++;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form name="myForm" method="POST">
        <p>
          <select name="inputSelect" onchange="addAllInputs(  'dynamicInputs', document.myForm.inputSelect.value);">
   <option value="" selected>--- Select ---</option>
   <option value="text">Text Field</option>
   <option value="label">Label</option>
   <option value="password">Password Field</option>
   <option value="email">e-Mail Field</option>
   <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
   <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
   <option value="dropdown">Drop Down</option>
   <option value="textarea">Text Area</option>
   <option value="button">Button</option>
   </select><br></p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 bdr">
      <form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-8 bdr" id="dynamicInputs" />
        <button id="register" value="Register" onclick="subreg()">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you tagged `jquery`? You aren't using any jquery code. Are you expecting an answer using JQuery?

Comment: Hi., Thanks for response, hoping that who knows jquery they have ability answering in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

Below is the JQuery code that would display the values of the field on clicking of the register button. You can check, play with it and can accordingly tweak it to meet your needs:

```js
var counterText = 0;
var counterpasswordfield = 0;
var counterRadioButton = 0;
var counterCheckBox = 0;
var counterTextArea = 0;
var counterButon = 0;
var counterdropdown = 0;
var counterlabel = 0;

function addAllInputs(divName, inputType) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  switch (inputType) {
    case 'text':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      if (x != null) {
        newdiv.innerHTML = "<label for='uname'>" + x + "</label>: <input type='" + inputType + "' id='myval' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
        counterText++;
      }
      break;
    case 'password':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='password' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
      counterpasswordfield++;
      break;
    case 'label':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + "<br>";
      counterlabel++;
      break;
    case 'email':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='email' name='myInputs[]'><br>";
      counterlabel++;
      break;
    case 'radio':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='radio' name='myRadioButtons[]'><br>";
      counterRadioButton++;
      break;
    case 'checkbox':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <input type='checkbox' name='myCheckBoxes[]'><br>";
      counterCheckBox++;
      break;
    case 'dropdown':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <Select selected><option>--- Select ---</option><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select><br>";
      counterdropdown++;
      break;
    case 'textarea':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = x + ": <textarea name='myTextAreas[]'>type here...</textarea>";
      counterTextArea++;
      break;
    case 'button':
      var x = prompt("Enter Label Name");
      newdiv.innerHTML = "<button>" + x + "</button>";
      counterButon++;
      break;
  }
  document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}

$("#register").on('click', function() {
  $("#dynamicInputs input").each(function() {
    $("#previewValues").append($(this).val());
  });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <form name="myForm" method="POST">
        <p>
          <select name="inputSelect" onchange="addAllInputs(  'dynamicInputs', document.myForm.inputSelect.value);">
   <option value="" selected>--- Select ---</option>
   <option value="text">Text Field</option>
   <option value="label">Label</option>
   <option value="password">Password Field</option>
   <option value="email">e-Mail Field</option>
   <option value="radio">Radio Button</option>
   <option value="checkbox">Check Box</option>
   <option value="dropdown">Drop Down</option>
   <option value="textarea">Text Area</option>
   <option value="button">Button</option>
   </select><br></p>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 bdr">
      <form name="myform" id="myform" method="POST">
        <div class="col-md-8 bdr" id="dynamicInputs" />
        <button id="register" value="Register">Register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
Preview:
<div id="previewValues"></div>
```

Comment: Well, I couldn't get label names because your DOM structure is not consistent. Some have `label` tags, some don't.